# is someone has any idea where can I edit ingress controller algorithm?

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes-ingress, distributed-computing, nginx-ingress

I installed the ingress controller on my Kubernetes machine with helm, but somehow have no idea where the ingress controller puts the configuration file to be edited. We can find the helm file through `helm list` but what I mean is the code of the program itself.
I want to edit some algorithms from the ingress controller to do some projects.

Now I am using [bitnami](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller). I want to try to find the code for the algorithm. But still confused about what to do and what to use. do I have to use docker? Do I need to edit with any specific apps? I am confused about where is the Nginx ingress algorithm file source code.

Comment: which ingress controller are you using ?

Comment: by now I am using bitnami, https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller/9.0.7. I want to try to find the code for the algorithm. bu still confused about what to do and what to use.

do I have to use docker? do I need to edit with any specific apps, and confused about where is the file for the Nginx algorithm located on the source code.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/helm-chart-4.0.17

Comment: Hi rthamrin, do you mean that you want to configure ingress rules like routing based on hostname, based on path, configuring backend and rewrite riles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good guide how to build the NGINX Ingress Controller Image on the official NGINX [website](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/building-ingress-controller-image/).
**Note**: this project is different from the NGINX Ingress controller in [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) repo.

So, change the ingress controller source code to tweak its algorithm and follow these steps:

1. Before you can build the image, make sure that the following software is installed on your machine:

- [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker)  v18.09+
- [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)
- [git](https://git-scm.com/)
- [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), optionally, if you would like to generate a self-signed certificate and a key for the default server.

2. Clone your Ingress Controller repo.
3. Build the image using `make` tool like this:
   `$ make debian-image PREFIX=myregistry.example.com/nginx-ingress TARGET=download`
   Check the Makefile [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/Makefile).
4. Push the image to your Docker registry like this:
   `$ make push PREFIX=myregistry.example.com/nginx-ingress TAG=your-tag`

###### After that, create your own Helm chart for your custom Ingress Controller.

Read this guide on how to create your first Helm Chart [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/create-your-first-helm-chart/). As a good production example you can take this [NGINX Ingress Controller Helm Chart](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/deployments/helm-chart). You need to change the referenced image.
Also, check [this guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) on how to install NGINX Ingress Controller using Helm.

I hope this gives a good idea of how to build a custom Ingress Controller from the source code.

**EDIT:**

As for Load balancer algorithms, there are several [built-in load balancer methods](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/3e6db807fc5b20a6095e6e812967f9fea5bb35ae/internal/configs/parsing_helpers.go#L111): least_conn, ip_hash, random, random two, random two least_conn.
You can choose the load balancer method using annotation `nginx.org/lb-method`. See more info [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/).

But if you still want to change the Load balancer algorithm, you will have to modify the source code and build a custom ingress controller or use some of the other existing ingress controllers.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I have done with ingress resource. What I mean is about the algorithm, as we know the Nginx ingress controller uses a round-robin algorithm to divide the load equally to run its function as Load Balancer. I would like to improve the algorithm inside it or do some modifications to improve the performance of the algorithm or the ingress itself.

Comment: Hi @rthamrin!  Please check my updated answer :)

Comment: thanks, man, It helps me a lot. You suggest building my own ingress controller from the source code and building my own image and modifying them later.

Comment: np @rthamrin :) Please, mark this as [Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answers your initial question.

Comment: thank you, but where is the algorithm file they put? which file to set the algorithm before I pull it as a docker image? or it is located /etc/Nginx/  after I install the ingress through helm?

Comment: Are you aware of [Advanced Configuration with Snippets](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-snippets/)? If existing ingress controllers do not suit you, and you want to create a custom ingress controller, the general approach is to make all changes you need in the source code and build it as I wrote in the answer, and then create your Helm chart. So, after installing a custom ingress controller to a Kubernetes cluster, you only create ingress resources (and not edit /etc/nginx config manually).

Comment: As for the ingress controller we discuss, check this [link](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/3e6db807fc5b20a6095e6e812967f9fea5bb35ae/internal/configs/parsing_helpers.go#L111). There are several built-in methods: least_conn, ip_hash, random, random two, random two least_conn. You can choose the load balancer using annotation `nginx.org/lb-method` like in the doc in my previous comment. But if you still want to change Load balancer algorithm, you will have to modify the source code and build a custom ingress controller or use some of the other existing ingress controllers.

Comment: Thank bro I think this is what I need. now I use the Nginx ingress controller community, https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx , but I hope this is also going to work for my ingress controller. Otherwise, I need to deploy from the beginning with the link that you shared.

Comment: how to accept it? somehow I don't think the algorithm from nginxinc/Kubernetes-ingress will work on https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/.

Comment: @rthamrin, you can tweak a load balancer algorithm for `kubernetes/ingress-nginx` using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balance` annotation. Check [this link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-load-balancing).  There are `round_robin` (the default) and `EWMA` methods for routing.

Comment: Thanks man, now this is exactly what I am trying to do. but it's kinda weird because I saw mine configure the EWMA load balancer as default, not round_robin. or I just misunderstood.  I make a new topic about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493725/load-balancer-algorithm-of-kuberentes-nginx-ingress

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any open source ingress controller you might be able to get the code.

**For example :**

Nginx ingress controller : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Kong ingress controller : https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller

there could be chances pro or plus features won't be there.

Comment: so I just download the source code from here, https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/helm-chart-4.0.17

and edit some source code for the algorithm and upload it using docker image? and pull the image by helm? i just want to make sure if I go in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Nginx ingress controller : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx i tried to makefile of image for the ingress, but I could  not. have any idea? ```make: *** No rule to make target 'debian-image'.  Stop``` but I have no any problem for this https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress

Comment: have to use the `make image` to build the image.

Comment: ```docker login```
```git checkout```
```make debian-image PREFIX=myregistry.in dokcerhub TARGET=download```

i followed the steps from the link https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/building-ingress-controller-image/

I could make a file image for https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/ and uploaded it to my docker but I could not do the same for kubernetes/ingress-nginx